# Different `next` entry of ConcurrentHashMap in JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

In JDK 1.6, Doug Lea uses `final` preceding the `next` field.

```
static final class HashEntry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    final int hash;
    volatile V value;
    final HashEntry<K,V> next;
```

Whereas in JDK 1.7, the `next` field is preceded by `volatile`. I also notice that in JDK 1.7, the `get` method adopts `getObjectVolatile` method to read the `value` field, which has the volatile load semantics.

I have no sense why Doug Lea previously uses `final`. If there are problems with correctness, then how could he replace it with `volatile` in JDK 1.7(also JDK 1.8)?

**Edit:**

Specifically, my question is that could we replace `final` with `volatile` in JDK 1.6's implementation?

Comment: This class is not in CHM in Java 8.

Comment: OK, if that's your question, then no, you can't. The reason the modifier was changed is that the implementation was completely changed. This is not an isolated change.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, could you present some details, or articles for the explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @assylias, sorry, the whole implementation is changed in Java 8, which uses `Node<K,V>` to represent the Key-value entry. I should point it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question:

> I have no sense why Doug Lea previously uses final. If there are
>   problems with correctness, then how could he replace it with volatile
>   in JDK 1.7(also JDK 1.8)?

It wasn't a matter of correctness. Both implementations are correct in terms of thread-safety.  What was trying to be solved was reducing the initial footprint of the CHM.  In Java 6, making the `next` field final required the object be created with at least a place holder.  This caused excessive empty object creation and so was changed to offer create-when-needed semantics.

> Specifically, my question is that could we replace final with volatile
>   in JDK 1.6's implementation?

Certainly as long as the operations continue to be sequentially consistent, which they are.

---

One of Doug Lea's comments touches on this design change

```
 /* 
 * ...
 * Historical note: The previous version of this class relied
 * heavily on "final" fields, which avoided some volatile reads at
 * the expense of a large initial footprint.  Some remnants of
 * that design (including forced construction of segment 0) exist
 * to ensure serialization compatibility. 
 */
```

So to answer another question you are probably having, why was `final` chosen initially? To prevent some volatile reads later on.

Comment: I have the same idea, but cannot confirm it by myself. I wonder if you come up with similar questions about Java APIs, how do you handle them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of replacing `final` with `volatile`. Like [RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) it was changed among many other methods. The purpose might be the optimization of `ConcurrentHashMap.remove()`. In JDK1.6 the list that stores bucket (objects grouped by hashcode) is CopyOnWrite so inside `remove()` part of list is copied, in JDK1.7 only `next` pointer is changed.